# I have big project in IntelliJ IDEA(UE) and list of External Libraries. How can I find where in the project I add this lib from the maven?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have jackson-core-2.9.0 in the list of External Libraries, but I cant find where I added this lib in the project

[image: External Libs]

Answer (score 0):

You must understand how maven dependency works.

If you add any dependency to your `pom.xml` which is direct dependency to your project.

Then those direct dependencies have direct dependencies of their own and those dependencies have direct dependencies of their own and so on until there are no direct dependencies, these are called transitive dependencies of your project.

Use `mvn dependency:tree` to display all you your dependencies in tree structure to find which direct dependency has `jackson-core-2.9.0` as dependency.

*Note: more than one direct dependency can have `jackson-core-2.9.0`(or any other dependency) as dependency*